# Retrieving a Twitter-verified user's Tweets in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, twitter

I need a bit of help understanding how to extract Tweets from a verified user. Sorry for the open-ended question, but here goes:

https://github.com/ttezel/twit enables you to retrieve the tweets of any Twitter handle. But in my use case, I need the user to log in to their Twitter account and retrieve their latest tweets so that I know that they are theirs and not someone else's.

I'm using angular.js and node.js - much help appreciated. I don't even know if this is something I should do client-side only, or on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user is followed by **`@verified`** [twitter account](https://twitter.com/verified) then the user is **verified**. 
You can check that by retrieving the followers.