# Check Whether the Facebook Profile and Page is Verified or not?

Tags: facebook

I had found an answer to check [**whether the twitter profile is verified**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446776/retrieving-a-twitter-verified-users-tweets-in-node-js/26446839#26446839). But is there any tricks of method for **Facebook**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can get the `verified` or `is_verified` (though I think you want `verified`) field for a user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

Comment: +1 - does not seem to be possible for pages though, no verified field in the page docs